# Javascript functions wrong sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a function that loads JSON from a server and displays it in a `div`, that gets dynamically created in the DOM. After the created div is displayed, I want to do other stuff like `parent.appendChild(x)`. Now it sometimes happens that the second step gets run before the first. I've tried to use this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$.ajax({
  url: firstfunction(),
  success: function() {
    parent.appendChild(x)
  }
});
```

Note that `firstfunction()` loads JSON and displays it inside a newly created div.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: `the second step gets run before the first` That's not possible as the callback only fires once the AJAX request completes with a successful HTTP response code. The small sample you've shown should work fine -
 assuming `x` is provided through the argument to the callback. We need to see more of your code, as it's more likely you have an error elsewhere in the page causing the issue

Comment: it does not return anything. It just loads json and displays it inside a newly created div. @AniketSahrawat

Comment: That's your problem then. Why are you doing that? The `url` property should be a string, or function which returns a string, that is the location to make the AJAX call to...

Comment: @Sarius _"it does not return anything"_ The way you're using it, it should return the value of the `url` property... -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Did you research how to make `$.ajax` calls, and looked at examples, before asking?

Comment: *"Note that firstfunction() loads JSON and displays it inside a newly created div"* Nothing in the quoted code ensures that that process is complete before making the second request, which may complete more quickly. Separately, the claim that `firstfunction` doesn't return anything suggests a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises, so you wait to finish your Ajax request before moving on to another task (for your example manipulate DOM).

```
async function doAjax(ajaxurl){

 const result = await $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl
 });
    return result;
}
//Call function
doAjax().then( data => doStuff(data) )
```

Async/Await with $.ajax example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpzJza

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by  just using a synchronous httprequest.